# Adding strings to a formatted string

Tags: python, excel-formula

I'm trying to add on to a string that is going into excel.

```
sheets_to_use = ["Dermott Wind_Mast 9530", "Dermott Wind_Mast 9531", "Dermott Wind_Mast 9532"]

    for num in range(2,14): # 2 through 13
        formula_string = "=AVERAGE(" + ",".join(["{}!B{}".format(str(i), str(num)) for i in sheets_to_use]) + ")"
        _ = summary_sheet.cell(row=name_row+num, column=3)
        _.value = formula_string
        _.number_format = '#,####0.0000'
        formula_string = "=AVERAGE(" + ",".join(["{}!C{}".format(str(i), str(num)) for i in sheets_to_use]) + ")"
        _ = summary_sheet.cell(row=name_row+num, column=4)
        _.value = formula_string
        _.number_format = '#,####0.0000'
```

But what's actually going into my cell in my sheet is:

```
=AVERAGE(Dermott Wind_Mast '9530'!B2,Dermott Wind_Mast '9531'!B2,Dermott Wind_Mast '9532'!B2)
```

The single quotes should be around the entire str(i), why is only the number getting the single quotes?

Comment: I'd suggest using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) instead. Also, it's not very good practice to use `_` as a variable name when you are actually performing operations on it or using it later. Use an actual descriptive variable name instead.

Comment: Why do you expect single quotes there?  You're not inserting them.  If `i` comes from `sheets_to_use`, then `str` of a string is a no-op.

Comment: I wasn't actually expecting them, they were just in the output and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the issue, but I also wasn't able to reproduce your problem. Here's how you could use f-strings to make your life easier though:

```py
sheets_to_use = ["Dermott Wind_Mast 9530",
                 "Dermott Wind_Mast 9531",
                 "Dermott Wind_Mast 9532"]

for num in range(2,14):
    # Note the use of single quotes inside this f-string:
    sheet_refs = ", ".join(f"'{s}!B{num}'" for s in sheets_to_use)
    formula_string = f"=AVERAGE({sheet_refs})"
    print(formula_string)
```

Output:

```py
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B2', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B2', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B2')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B3', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B3', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B3')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B4', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B4', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B4')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B5', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B5', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B5')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B6', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B6', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B6')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B7', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B7', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B7')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B8', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B8', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B8')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B9', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B9', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B9')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B10', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B10', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B10')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B11', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B11', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B11')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B12', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B12', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B12')
=AVERAGE('Dermott Wind_Mast 9530!B13', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9531!B13', 'Dermott Wind_Mast 9532!B13')
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, using `_` as a variable name on which you perform operations is bad practice. The `_` is used to signify to other readers that the value of the variable is unimportant and will not be used later in any capacity. Always give your variables descriptive names!

Comment: This worked! I'm also not sure why the single quotes were being put around the number in the original but this fixes it. I originally tried join in a loop but it added each character individually. Also, I'm adapting the program here from what someone else wrote, so I'll keep in mind the _ var name as I move through. Thank you!